Why does importing a module from a library (that was imported from another library) not work?
I'm trying to write code that does the following:

Import module A in library A into library B as module A/B (same name).
Import module A/B from library B as module A/B into script C.
Run function A from module A/B in script C.

I know this is an inefficient way of running function A in script C, but I'm mainly doing this to try to understand the python import system better.
Here's a test I wrote:
Directory:
Init_Package_Import
    Domain
        app
            app.py
        lib
            __init__.py
    Framework
        __init__.py
        client.py

Content of Init_Package_Import/Framework/_init_.py:
# Init_Package_Import/Framework/_init_.py

Content of Init_Package_Import/Framework/client.py:
# Init_Package_Import/Framework/client.py:

def hi_client():
    print("Hi Client")

Content of Init_Package_Import/Domain/lib/_init_.py:
# Init_Package_Import/Domain/lib/__inti__.py:

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'Init_Package_Import')

from Framework import client as client

Content of Init_Package_Import/Domain/app/app.py:
# Init_Package_Import/Domain/app/app.py:

sys.path.insert(0, 'Init_Package_Import/Domain')

# import method 1 - works
from lib import client as client1

# import method 2 - throws error
import lib.client as client2

When I run python3 Init_Package_Import/Domain/app/app.py, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.client' error. Why does the first import work and the second doesn't?

from x import y ends at function level
but import x.y only support file level
